# Detecting which way a car, in an image, is pointing (what is this type of problem called)

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, classification

I have about 2,000 images of cars, most pointing right, but some pointing left.

I'd like to find a way of automatically tagging a car with it's direction (new images will be coming in continually).

I'm struggling to get started and wondered if this kind of image detection problem has a name that may help my searches. Is object orientation detection a thing?

I'm a software developer (not doing much ML or Image stuff) and have a ton of azure and gcc resources available, but I can't find anything to solve this.  Azure Cognitive Service can tell us it's a car in the picture, but doesn't tell us the direction.

Could just do with a good starting point to get going.

Should add, the images are quite clean on white backgrounds, examples:
[image: Left car]

[image: Right car]

Comment: can you try a simple classification model, which answers binary ? (left - 0, right - 1).  I am presuming it to work, because the headlight, side mirrors are the features which are the ones that decides the direction. and covolution feature maps should gets activated accordingly and classify accordingly. I am suggesting this idea, since you mentioned you have enough resources.

Comment: We tried to use a custom image classifier (custom vision) on azure cognitive services last night, we loaded in 300 right pointing cars and 60 left pointing cars and tagged everything correctly and let the model train and did a few iterations with different images, but we can't get much accuracy out of it.  Will keep trying to see if we can find a way.  Will read up more on feature maps!

Comment: 300 vs 60 too biased on right dont you think ? Can you trigger the training with almost equal number of images? Also make sure you dont use any augmentations like horizontal flip, rotate which spoils the whole purpose. (p.s. I have made similar mistake once. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Venkata for commenting, it was a bad dataset causing our issues (too many rights vs left).

Here's what we did to get it all working:

We set up a training and prediction instance in azure (using custom vision cognitive services in our portal).

We then used https://www.customvision.ai/ to set everything up and train the model (it's super simple).

We didn't actually need any left facing images in the end, we just took all the right facing images we had (about 500 in the final instance), we uploaded them all with the tag "Right".  We then mirrored all the images with a photoshop script and then uploaded them all again with a "Left" tag.  It trained for about 15 minutes and we ended up with a 100% prediction score.  We tested it with a load of images that weren't contained in the training set to confirm it was all working.

We then did the same for a ton of van/truck images, these were taken from a different angle (cars were all side profile shots, the vans were all front 3 quarter so we weren't sure if we'd have the same success).

Again, we flipped the images ourselves to create the left images so we only needed to source right facing vans to create the whole model.

We ended up with a 99.8% score, which is totally acceptable for our use case and we can now detect all cars and van directions and it even detects car directions that are front 3 quarters and vans that are in profile (even though we only trained cars in profile and vans in 3 quarter).

The custom vision portal gives you an API endpoint and a key, now when we detect a new image in our system it goes via the API (using the custom image sdk/nuget in our .net site) and we check the tags to see if it needs flipping.  If it does, we flip it and save it back to the disk and it's then cached so it doesn't keep hitting the API.

It's pretty amazing, it took us just two days to research the options, pick a provider and then implement the solution in to a production platform.  It's probably a simple use case for ML, but 10 years ago (or even 5) we couldn't have dreamed that things would have come along so far.

tldr; If you need to detect if an object in an image is pointing left or right, just grab a lot of right facing examples and then flip them yourself to create a well balanced model.  Obviously, this relies on the object looking the same from one side to the other.